# How to gzip specific files in a certain folder?

Tags: gzip

Good Day.

I am creating a script that moves all 'logA' files in a certain folder and adds timestamp every 3 hours, afterwards it will be zipped.

This is the base of the script:

```
cd /logs
mv *logA+timestamp /backupDIR
cd /backupDIR
```

--then the GZIP part--

Since it will run every 3 hours, there will be a time there are already .gzip files in the /backupDIR.
Sample:

```
logA.07132020-16.00.gz
logA.07132020-19.00.gz
logA.07132020-22.00.gz
logA.07142020-02.00
```

How can I exclude the already zipped file in the script? Should I do loop that will check if there are still .logA+timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

The `gzip` program already does this for you: It refuses to zip `.gz` files with

```
gzip: <file>.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged
```

So you don't need to exclude the already zipped files.
To suppress the error message, use `gzip -q`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided the `gzip` command you are running, I'm going to assume you are doing something trivial along the lines of `gzip *` or `gzip someprefix*`, and these will probably work in the majority of circumstances (taking note of [Juergen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598958/40482).)

However, if there are lots of files in the directory that you don't want to consider (and only a few that you do) it *could* cause an issue with parameter exhaustion (and/or a small speed hit while `gzip` is figuring out which files to work with).

There are numerous ways to tackle that, here's one:

```
find /backupDIR -type f ! -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 gzip
```

If you have sub directories that you don't want to traverse amend as follows:

```
find /backupDIR -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 gzip
```